# Not able to run file when running from relative path in windows 10 cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

I have below directory structure :

OrganicEcommerceFrontend --> node --> node_modules -->@angular -->cli --> bin

bin folder contains ng file.

Now, if I'm going inside this bin path and running below command from cmd.

```
ng --version
```

It is running fine and showing me about angular version details.

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.2
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
```

But If I'm running below command from OrganicEcommerceFrontend dir, via cmd.

```
node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng --version
```

It is giving me below error

```
'node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Similarly, If I'm running ***local_angular_cli_version.bat*** file(inside OrganicEcommerceFrontend folder)

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
echo %~dp0
%~dp0node\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng %arg1%
```

```
C:\Users\Vikas Yadav\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.0.RELEASE\OrganicEcommerceFrontend\
'C:\Users\Vikas' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Can someone help me here. 
I wanted to run **"ng --version"** (or any ng command ) from OrganicEcommerceFrontend directory.

NOTE: I already have angular cli (of version 6) installed globally, so wanted to run specific version locally.

Comment: One line with doublequotes, `@"%~dp0node\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.exe" %1`, should do it.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for help here. Still getting the same issue,

'"C:\Users\<path to OrganicEcommerceFrontend>\OrganicEcommerceFrontend\node\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Also ng is not .exe file, it is script file.

I have verified path till bin folder, it is valid. Also ng file reside inside this bin folder.

Comment: Well if your directory only has `ng` instead of both `ng` and `ng.exe` just use `@"%~dp0node\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %1` then! If that doesn't do what you want, I would suggest that you need to tell the system which executable file use to invoke `ng`.